# php count returns 1 for empty array solution on server

Tags: php

I need to php count returns 0 for empty using server or mysql. Actually, in my case lot of places i have used count function, when i am upload my code to client server php count returns 1 for empty.So that it is create many issue. If any solution then please reply me. I am not want to change all the places where count used.

Comment: Show the array. Use `array_filter`.

Comment: We need code samples with data samples

Comment: It is simple example,
$TempArr = array();
echo count($TempArr);//Output = 1 than 0
I am not want any change in this code, want to change server configuration or mysql.

Comment: If your queries began to return false instead of array() may be you have more serious troubles with your queries.

Answer (score 6):

If i am not getting you wrong, you are passing a **non-array** element to `count`.
Look at following example code..

**Code 1:**

```
$var = false;
echo count($var); // print 1
```

**Code 2:**

```
$var = array();
echo count($var); // print 0
```

**Code 3:**

```
$var = array('');
echo count($var); // print 1
```

So better you should check whether the element is an array or not.

```
if(is_array($var))
{
   $var = array_filter($var);
   echo count($var);
}
else
{
   echo 0;
}
```

See **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/POyUAkSX)**.

Comment: In most of case count(Blank Array) return 0, but in my client server it return 1. I have used that code in many places. I am not want to changes code. If any solution related to database or server to set that value then please let me know....

Comment: I have write code for select query. It is give me blank array. When i am use count($ResultArray), it is return 1 than 0. Actually that should be return 0 that 1. If you have any solution without change php code means changes server setting or database then please let me know. In my server it is return 0 but on client server it is return 1.

Comment: No. You must have to change your code. There is not any server setting to solve this kinda problem.

Comment: then why it is return 0 for most other server ?